# Can I have a field populate based on the value of another field on a Sharepoint List?

Tags: custom-list

I have a sharepoint list with a dropdown called "Country". I want a field called "Region" which is populated automatically based on the value in Country. I don't want the user to select the Region, I just want it to appear.
Is this possible?

Comment: Does it have to appear in the forms, or is it enough that its visible in the list view?